# Web development — 100% code separation vs flexibility

Tags: web-development

This is probably a holywarish topic, but nevertheless.

In a perfect content management system of your dream, would you rather want a templating system that is completely, 100% separate from your code, and uses declarative syntax to produce (X)HTML (such as `<your code>` -> DOM/XML -> XSLT -> HTML), or would you rather choose a system that lets your code cook HTML fragments, and then runs some template assembly to put these pieces together to output a complete page?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

To make it probably a bit more clear, I mean that HTML is a declarative 'language', whereas most of the dynamic stuff is done in imperative/functional languages. Templates glue the two together, but the way they do it isn't always clean (as in clean separation of paradigms).

Comment: I already have perfect separation between templating and code.  It's not a dream system.  It's Django.  I don't understand the question.   It seems that perfect separation is the way many systems are built.

Comment: "but the way they [glue HTML declarative and imperative] isn't always clean".  What does that mean?  Are you complaining about loop and decision constructs in the template language?

Comment: or am I complaining at all?

Comment: @etranger: "isn't always clean"?  This is a complaint.  If it's not supposed to be a complaint, you need to avoid subjective value judgements like "clean".

Comment: I disagree, but then again, English is not my native. I was making a statement, if you will. Clean = conforming to paradygm. Anyway, I suggest we leave it as it is, I get your point, thank you.

Comment: @etranger: "not conforming to paradigm"?  Please define that more clearly, please.  "Not" is negative.  It indicates a complaint.  I don't know which "paradigm" things are supposed to conform to.  I don't know what things are supposed to confirm to the paradigm.  You have lots of things and two paradigms.  Please be more clear.

Comment: "Not" does not indicate a complaint at all. My Mac Dictionary states that complaint is "a statement that a situation is unsatisfactory or unacceptable", which I have not stated.

Comment: @etranger: "not conforming to paradigm" == "situation is unsatisfactory or unacceptable".  Sounds like a complaint.  Also, please clarify the paradigm and the separation you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

If the popularity of Ruby on Rails, Django and ASP.NET MVC have taught us anything it is that a clean, MVC-style web framework combined with HTML-like templating that has nearly full language access is the way to go. Can developers make bad decisions about where to put formatting code? Sure. But I'd rather take that risk then deal with the necessary hacks and tricks one needs to do in a system with full separation. Tell me again, how does one format a date in XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

The Xml => XSLT => HTML path is probably overkill. Better just to use a template to output the HTML you need.

Comment: Overkill as in too complex, too much to learn, too much resource overhead or something else?

Comment: My two cents: Too complex, more resource overhead than you need and more of a pain in the ass to maintain than HTML templates.